# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for non-differentiable convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis, subgradient, non-smooth-analysis

Suppose $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex set and $f:C\to\mathbb{R}$ is a convex function. I wonder if the following statement is true.

> Suppose $g:C\to\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies $g(x)\in\partial f(x)$ for all $x\in C$. Then for all $x,y\in C$, it holds that
> $$
> f(y)-f(x)=\int_0^1g(x+t(y-x))^T(y-x)\ dt.
> $$

I think I can prove that this is true, but I couldn't find such a result online, so I wonder if my proof is incorrect. Are there any references that contain this kind of result?

---

**My proof:** Let $\ell(t)=f(x+t(y-x))$. Then $\ell:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is convex, and
$$
\partial\ell(t)=\lbrace d^T(y-x):d\in\partial f(x+t(y-x))\rbrace.
$$
In particular, $g(x+t(y-x))^T(y-x)\in\partial\ell(t)$. Since $\ell$ is convex, then for almost every $t\in[0,1]$, $\ell$ is differentiable at $t$, and thus $g(x+t(y-x))^T(y-x)=\ell'(t)$. Moreover, since $\ell$ is convex, then $\ell$ is locally Lipschitz hence absolutely continuous on every compact interval. Therefore,
$$
f(y)-f(x)=\ell(1)-\ell(0)=\int_0^1\ell'(t)\ dt=\int_0^1g(x+t(y-x))^T(y-x)\ dt.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible reference could be **Theorem 2.3.4** (p. 179) of the following textbook:

*Hiriart-Urruty, Jean-Baptiste; Lemaréchal, Claude*, Fundamentals of convex analysis, Grundlehren. Text Editions. Berlin: Springer. x, 259 p. (2001). [ZBL0998.49001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0998.49001).